# php date->foramt() return object instead of string

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I want to output a date object as string using `->format()` but when i return the function php automatically convert it to string? how do i prevent that?

```
function setPassword($currOrder) {

            $checkInDate = $currOrder->checkInDate; // return date object 
            $checkIndate = $checkInDate->format('j/m/Y'); 
            print_r(gettype($checkIndate)); // output string

            return $checkInDate;
        }

print_r( gettype($thisGuest->setPassword($thisOrder)) );  // return object
```

Comment: at least tell why the down vote?

Comment: `$checkInDate` !== `$checkIndate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the problem is caused becaus variables are [case-sensitive](http://php.net/manual/de/language.variables.basics.php), so `$checkIndate` and `$checkInDate` are two different variables. Correct this and you should be fine.